# SQL select grouped results

Tags: sql, sql-server

I need to create a report in the following format (the first row with the | delimiters contains the column headers, the total for all accounts is the sum of the Account.Value for a given AE, and the account names and values are grouped under each AE by account name ascending, ordered by AE first name ascending):

```
AE             |    Account Value                      | # of Calls
Amy Adams           $5000 (total for all accounts) 
  *Acme Inc.        $1000                                5
  *Noon Inc.        $3000                                7  
  *Tazo Inc.        $1000                                2
Ben Smith           $7000 (total for all accounts) 
  *Airo Inc.        $2000                                9
  *Fifa Inc.        $5000                                8  
Dan Morse           $2000 (total for all accounts) 
  *Yakk Inc.        $1000                                1
  *Zero Inc.        $1000                                2
```

from the following tables:

```
Table [AE]
Column [AeId] int
Column [FirstName] varchar
Column [LastName] varchar

Table [Account]
Column [AccountId] int
Column [Name] varchar
Column [Value] decimal
Column [AeId] int (foreign key AE.AeId)

Table [Call]
Column [CallId] int
Column [DateCreated] datetime
Column [AccountId] int (foreign key Account.AccountId)
```

Any help would be appreciated, as I'm not sure how to group the data in this fashion. 
Thanks for any suggestions.

Comment: That is a broad topic.    Which part of it are you having trouble with?    What did you try and what error did you get?

Comment: It would be much better if you gave sample data and desired output, with beautiful format of structures of your tables, now it's not difficult to give you an answer but if you consider the points I mentioned answering you will be much more easier, also it's better to try something before asking

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try things like WITH ROLLUP or WITH CUBE...

But I would just use a CTE like this:

```
create Table [AE] (
[AeId] int,
[FirstName] varchar(50),
[LastName] varchar(50)
)
create Table [Account] (
[AccountId] int,
[Name] varchar(50),
[Value] decimal,
[AeId] int
)
create Table [Call] (
[CallId] int,
[DateCreated] datetime,
[AccountId] int
)
insert into ae values (1, 'Brett', 'Green')
insert into ae values (2, 'John', 'Doe')
insert into account values (1, 'Account 1', 10000, 1)
insert into account values (2, 'Account 2', 5000, 1)
insert into account values (3, 'Account 3', 3000, 1)
insert into account values (4, 'Account 4', 1000, 2)
insert into account values (5, 'Account 5', 5000, 2)
insert into account values (6, 'Account 6', 3000, 2)

insert into call values (1, current_timestamp, 1)
insert into call values (2, current_timestamp, 1)
insert into call values (3, current_timestamp, 2)
insert into call values (4, current_timestamp, 3)
insert into call values (5, current_timestamp, 4)
insert into call values (6, current_timestamp, 5)
insert into call values (7, current_timestamp, 5)

;WITH data as (
SELECT 
    ae.FirstName + ' ' + ae.LastName AS Name,
    a.Name AS AccountName,
    SUM(a.Value) AS AccountValue,
    COUNT(DISTINCT c.CallId) AS NumberOfCalls
FROM AE ae
INNER JOIN Account a
    ON a.AeId = ae.AeId
INNER JOIN Call c
    ON c.AccountId = a.AccountId
GROUP BY
    ae.FirstName + ' ' + ae.LastName,
    a.Name
)
select Name, '' AS AccountName, SUM(AccountValue) AS AccountValue, SUM(NumberOfCalls) AS NumberOfCalls
from data
group by Name
union all
select Name, AccountName, AccountValue, NumberOfCalls
from data
order By name
```

Comment: And I typically would do subtotals in 'code' rather than directly in the query. SQL is just generally not very good at that kind of thing.

Comment: SQL Server specific example above

Comment: How would you show the Account.Name, Account.Value rows grouped under each AE?

Comment: That would have to be a UI thing... there's no way to really do that in sql alone. I've simulated it with the query by 'NULLing' out the account name for the subtotal row